# Is it possible to access the FieldValue with node js cloud functions?

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I am trying to remove a user from a map that I declared in the FireStore. But how do I get the field value? I think it should be something like this `firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(user.uid)` only firestore does not have the FieldValue object. How can I remove user from he users map?

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

const firestore = admin.firestore();

export const onUserDeleted = functions.region('europe-west1').auth.user().onDelete(async user => {
    const groups = await firestore.collection('groups').where('users', 'array-contains', user.uid).get();
    const promises : Promise<FirebaseFirestore.WriteResult>[] = [];
    groups.forEach(snapshot => {
        promises.push(snapshot.ref.update({
            'users' : ,
        }));
    }); 
    return await Promise.all(promises);
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When using the Firebase Admin SDK, using the import shown in your code, you reference FieldValue by `admin.firestore.FieldValue`.

Comment: What is the difference between admin.firestore() and admin.firestore ?

Comment: You can see in the source - click through to the definition in VS Code (if that's what you're using).  The former is a function the returns an instance of Firestore.  The latter is a namespace.

Comment: How would you do this with `firebase-admin` [10 or newer](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/migrate-node-v10) with the new modular API pattern?

Answer (score 3):

**Note: I have tried the above solution and that did not work.**

I have been searching for this for like a whole day and found the solution from one of the firebase NodeJS snippets repositories. I know it is not in typescript so just change the import accordingly.

```
// for the import part
const {getFirestore, FieldValue} = require("firebase-admin/firestore");
// also, getFirestore is another import I needed and you might not so change accordingly

// for the update
await admin
 .firestore()
 .collection("Posts").doc(docId).update({
   postImages: FieldValue.arrayUnion(signedUrl),
 }).then((_) => {
    functions.logger.log("Updated the image link successfully");
 });
```